# Dynamically Increase Java EE servers

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture

If you see more traffic coming to your site, how do you dynamically add more Java EE servers?

The interviewer, on phone, suggested that this is possible without cloud and asked about cobernator. I googled this later and could not find anything. What are the other ways of dynamically adding servers?

Comment: While I can't speak for many javaee app servers and I'm not sure if clustering is part of the javaee spec, Jboss ships with clustering and load-balancing support. So what you'd want here is a cluster of nodes, fronted by a load balancer (or just mod_jk) to have high-availability

Answer (score 0):

Answering lately :

1. Cloud
2. Clustering
3. Dockers
4. Hardware switches or load balancers

As you have mentioned `cloud` I assume you are aware of the way it works there and clustering is pretty standard fashion. so let me explain 3 & 4.

Dockers : In a single system with huge capacity of hardware available, as load increases if you deploy more and more docker instances then you can scale to your needs. This is also called horizontal scaling. We can also go for vertical scaling and would look more like could fashioned with docker taste.

Hardware : There are hardware load balancers like from Radware or Cisco just plugin and configure your hardware switches and you are up and running.